# UIAlertController removes tabbar on segue

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have an `alertController`:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: "Your book has been uploaded", preferredStyle: .alert)
let PostBook = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: { action in self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "PostBook", sender: nil)})

alertController.addAction(PostBook)
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

print("Posted to Firebase. ")
```

In the `UIAlertAction`, I have an action to segue, and every time I segue, it whites out the tab bar. The tab bar is still there, it justs whites it out, which I don't want. The segue is a show segue.

before segue: 
[image]

after segue:[image]

Comment: If possible share the screenshot for better understanding.

Comment: @Imad the tab bar is still there, the icons are just gone. I put in screensshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed in a `navigationController` to your `view` so that all the segues goes through the `navigationController` instead.

[image]

Second view controller:
[image]

Comment: I did that and every other segue in my project perform the segue without removing the tab bar item. The only difference between other segues and this one is that this one is in a UIAlertController

Comment: I forgot to mention that the current page I am seguing from has the tabbar hidden on purpose

Comment: Have you tried to set it to visible try in your next view controller?

Comment: it works when I set the tab bar to visible however, I set the tab bar to visible in the storyboard by checking Hide Bottom bar on push and now I am having a hard time hiding the tab bar in the view controller that I need to hide it programmatically

Comment: Yes, because when you set it to visible false in one viewController it will inherit that value in the next one too. So it works for you now?

Comment: it works but now the initial controller that I want an invisible tab bar for, now has a visible tab bar and I don't know how to set it to invisible without clicking the Hide Bottom bar on push in storyboard

Comment: In your `viewWillAppear` function for each view controller you need to set whether you want it visible or not.